# RAILS: Nil class for belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-forms, nested-attributes, belongs-to

I want to make nested form. I have:

**advert.rb**

```
has_many :photos
belongs_to :car

accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
accepts_nested_attributes_for :car
```

**controller.rb**

```
def new
    @advert = Advert.new
    @advert.photos.new # OK
    @advert.car.new    # ERROR
end
```

So for `@advert.photos.new` everything is ok (form generating `advert[photos_attributes][o][image]`) but for `@advert.car.new` i'm gettings error: `undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass`

**UPD 1:**
After reading tonns of articles about nested_attributes, i understood that we can't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for parent in children (`belongs_to`) model.

So, what is the best way to achieve my goal? Make complex form from example i provided in this question?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
@advert.car = Car.new
```

instead. This is how you build associations in Rails.

**Update**

As for using nesting for parents, you can do something like this **I realize there may be a better way of accomplishing this**

In the controller, have something like this:

```
def create
  @advert = Advert.new(advert_params)
  @advert.car = Car.new(car_params)

  if @advert.save && @advert.car.save
  ...
  end
end

private

  def advert_params
    params.require(:advert).permit(...whitelisted stuff...)
  end

  def car_params
    params.require(:car).permit(...whitelisted stuff...)
  end
```

Comment: Undefine method `build` for nil class

Comment: also look at my **UPD 1**

Comment: Should be `build_car` for singular association.  See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html.

Comment: Sorry, should have caught that. See my update. Or do as @ihaztehcodez says. Both work.

Comment: @ihaztehcodez Already tried that and it is displaying on the form, BUT only without `accepts_nested_attributes_for :car`. Probably because of what i described in **UPD 1**.

Comment: I have used accepts_nested_attributes_for for parents in children before. It may not be best practice, for all I know, but it was effective.

Comment: How?? do you have example? Because your code is not working (not rendering fields). Also, according to api.rubyonrails: `Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent`

Comment: Building something quick now to confirm. In the meantime, are you saving the Car object separately in the create action? `@advert.save` won't save the car. You would have to also do `@advert.car.save`. (Heck, you might even be able to JUST do `@advert.car.save`).

Comment: See new update. It's a bit more involved than I remember, but it works